# Thinkpad, Windows, middle button for "open in new tab" and scroll

Tags: thinkpad, scrolling, mouse-buttons, synaptics-touchpad

There apparently is [tpmiddle](http://users.v-lo.krakow.pl/~mwrobel/programs/tpmiddle.html) to make the middle button work like a scroll wheel PLUS a wheel press click. But the link to the synaptics SDK is broken. How can I make my middle trackpad button work "correctly". I do not have the "neither" option in y trackpad driver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thinkpad trackpoint: scrolling and middle click possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/91074/thinkpad-trackpoint-scrolling-and-middle-click-possible)

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of the touchpad drivers don't enable this setting, and also disables the three-finger swipe gesture as well.  The only way I've gotten these features to work is to hunt down an older version of my touchpad driver, then prevent windows from updating it.  In general, you're looking for windows 8.1 drivers from before 2014.

**WARNING: This approach is somewhat involved and only gives a general approach.  You need to be comfortable with the device manager and editing group policies.  Since details vary between thinkpad models, it's not terribly specific either.**

The driver that worked for my 64-bit t520 was: 6hgx53ww.exe -- this filename will vary by windows version and laptop model.  Look for older versions of thinkpads in your series-- with models from after 2014 or so, you might be out of luck.

The general idea is:

1. Find the relevant driver for your system-- again, a windows 8.1 driver from before 2015, but hopefully not too far before.
2. Go to "Programs and Features" and uninstall any existing touchpad  drivers.  Look for Synaptics or Elan-- but make sure you're only hitting touchpad drivers and not bluetooth or such.
3. Disable your internet connection so Windows can't go out and grab a fresh copy of the driver by itself (yes, it may try to).
4. Go to the device manager, find the touchpad (usually in Mice and other pointing devices").  Right-click and select properties.
5. Click the "Details" tab, then inside that tab use the "Property" drop-down to select "Hardware Ids."  This will be a list of strings.  Copy-paste all of them out to a text file and save them for later.
6. Under the "Drivers" tab, click "Uninstall Driver"
7. Restart your computer.
8. Install the new driver you got from step 1.
9. Now we're going to tell Windows to never, ever update this driver with a Group Policy.  I'm going to let Howtogeek explain this; they do it better than me: http://www.howtogeek.com/263851/how-to-prevent-windows-from-automatically-updating-specific-drivers/ **NOTE:** If you ever have to modify those drivers yourself, this policy will *prevent you* from doing so.  You'll have to disable that rule to do so.
10. Make sure everything is working.  If it is, reboot your PC to make sure the GP rule from 9 applied, re-enable your internet connection, and get on with your life.

All told, a third-party app might involve fewer headaches.

EDIT: Fixed the Ultranav version I was using.